# Changing paragraph multiple times to match images changed in a slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to get my background-image slideshow to display different text depending on the image that is currently shown.
The changeText is what i would like to change when the "buttonR" is clicked.

```js
var images = [
    'http://i67.tinypic.com/1zlazia.jpg', //tesla
    'http://i67.tinypic.com/2hcq2xy.jpg', //galileo
    'http://placehold.it/500x320/7f0',
    'http://placehold.it/500x320/0f7'
  ],
  i = 0,
  n = images.length;

$("#buttonR").click(function() {
  $(".changable").css({
    backgroundImage: "url(" + images[i++ % n] + ")"
  });
});
```

```css
.parallax {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.contentBox {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 100px;
  font-size: 140%;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="parallax changable">
  <div class="module">
    <div class="moduleContent contentBox">
      <p id="changeText">
        <!-- this is the text for the first image that will show on load -->
        Nikola Tesla
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="buttonR" style="width:50px; background-color:white;">&rarr;</div>
</section>
```

I have used JavaScript and J Query to change the background image when user clicks the button, this works well i would like to know how i can make it so when the image is changed so is the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not convert your `images` array to an array of objects instead?

```
var images = [
    { image: 'http://i67.tinypic.com/1zlazia.jpg', name: 'Nikola Tesla' },
    { image: 'http://i67.tinypic.com/2hcq2xy.jpg', name: 'Galileo' }
];
```

Then you could have your click function reference the object properties:

```
$("#buttonR").click(function(){
    $(".changable").css({backgroundImage: "url("+ images[i % n].image +")" });
    $("#changeText").text(images[i % n].name);
    i++;
});
```

Comment: That works perfectly for what i want to do, thankyou for your help.